# Visualizar esquema de tablas (visual) en PgAdmin al estilo MySql

Tags: mysql, postgresql, pgadmin

Estoy utilizando PgAdmin y me gustaría saber si una vez cargada la BD se puede visualizar el esquema como en MySql que puedes visualizar de forma gráfica las tablas y sus respectivas relaciones,

Gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Parece que solo es posible en las últimas versiones de PgAdmin 4, [en este video se explica](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2pxVCzRFGeg). También puedes utilizar otras herramientas descritas en la [wiki de postgresql](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Design_Tools).